# R studio set x axis by year values

Tags: r, graph

I need to draw the following graph:

On X axis I have 72 values which represents the months from 2015 to 2020.
On Y axis I can have value from 0 to 5.

This is my code with x values divided in wrong way:

```
yval=round(runif(72, 0, 5))
plot(yval, type="l", col="red")
```

[image: This is my output]

I would like to see my x axis divided by year values, in my case: **2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020**

- 2015 in position 0,
- 2016 in position 12,
- 2017 in position 24,
- 2018 in position 32,
- 2019 in position 48,
- 2020 in position 60
- And no other values.

Something like the x axis of the following graph:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, to be honest. Where do the years come from? All you've presented is a 72-long vector of discrete `numeric`.

Comment: @r2evans I need to have these values on my x axix (2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020). each one every 12 values of my 72 of vector. Like the second graph i've posted.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add that constraint. Literally, though, is it just `xval <- rep(2015:2020, times=12)` and `plot(xval, yval, ...)`?

Comment: Your "desired" plot has more components than your simple `yval` example. While I appreciate your attempt at a simple MWE, I think it's over-simplified. It sounds like in addition to `yval` (number of sites), we also have at a minimum "year-month" (fractional year) in order to support the continuous x-axis. For the multiple lines, we'll also eventually need a "site" variable. This is all very straight-forward with `ggplot2`.

Comment: @r2evans I have edited my question, I am not interesting in multiple lines, but only in my x axis representation values. I need only to see 2015 (at position 0), 2016 at (position 12)..2020 in position 60 and nothing else. I don't find anything about that on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xaxt="n'` to disable the automatic axis labeling, and `axis(.)` to add your own.

```r
plot(yval, type="l", col="red", xaxt="n")
axis(1, c(0,12,24,36,48,60), 2015:2020)
```

[image]

(BTW, I changed 32 to 36, I thought it would align better :-)

Comment: Thanks! (May I suggest that you go back to some/all of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824139/fra96?tab=questions) with reasonable answers and accept and possibly upvote them?)